# Probability $P(X>Y,X>Z)$ for independent normal random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

There are several answers already given for working out the probability of one random variable being greater than another, but I can't make the leap to working out the probability of one random variable being greater than several others. My random variables are independent and normally distributed.
For example:

> Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be independent normal random variables. What is $P(X>Y,X>Z)$?

The obvious (to me) answer, being to just multiply the two probabilities $P(X>Y)$ and $P(X>Z)$ does not work because the difference random variables $(X-Y)$ and $(X-Z)$ are not independent.

**Edit**

For $P(X>Y)$ the answer is:
$$
{\rm P}(X  > Y )  = \Phi \left(\frac{\mu_X - \mu_Y }{\sqrt{\sigma_Y^2 + \sigma_Y^2}}\right).
$$
I'm hoping for a way of adding a third normal random variable to the equation. If this is possible I presume the answer can be easily expanded to add further random variables.

Comment: Are the variances of $X,Y,Z$ the same or different?

Comment: These are identical random variables?  If so, the answer is $\frac 13$.  One of them has to be greatest, nothing to break the symmetry.

Comment: lulu's symmetry argument applies to *any* case of independent and identically distributed random variables (normal is not necessary), provided $P(X=a)=0$ for all $a$.

Comment: @GregMartin: The variances (and means) are different.

Comment: @Did: Thank you for editing the question to improve it.

Comment: Just logged in to mark off an answer as accepted and vote it up... Now the answer has apparently been deleted. The effort was appreciated and helped me - if the answer or a summary of it gets put up again I'll accept it...

Answer (score -1):

Can be written in the below form ,

$$P(X>Z,X>Y)= P(X> \min(Y,Z)) \ ( P(Y>Z) \text{ or } P(Y<Z))$$

$$ P(X> \min(Y,Z)) =P(X>Y) \ P(X>Z) $$

Hope it helps.